# Compartilhar classes entre programas no Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

É possível compartilhar uma classe entre diferentes programas em Python?
Onde trabalho desenvolvi algumas automações com o python, sendo que algumas das automações utilizam de partes de classes comum, como por exemplo, a minha classe Sap, que faz integração e busca alguns dados no SAP. Seria muito bom se eu conseguisse compartilhar a classe entre dois programas.

No caso abaixo, tenho a automação no diretório 2 que usa a mesma classe do diretório 1, porém, como eu não consegui importar a classe do diretório 1, eu fiz uma cópia para o diterório 2 para conseguir importar. O lado negativo é que qualquer alteção que eu fizer na classe, vou ter que copiar e colar no outro diretório... Há alguma outra forma de compartilhar a mesma classe entre programas?

DIRETÓRIO 1 - ONDE ESTÁ A CLASSE ORIGINAL
Automações\AUTOMAÇÃO SEGURADORAS\source code\Controller\Sap.py

DIRETÓRIO 2 - ONDE FIZ A CÓPIA DO ARQUIVO DA CLASSE
Automações\DVE - DECLARAÇÃO DE VENDAS\source code\Scripts\Sap.py

Comment: Utilizando a biblioteca **sys** é possível importar as funções dentro de um programa, acredito que com as classes de certo também. Segue um modelo que uso para importar as configurações/funções de um banco de dados: 
`import sys` | `sys.path.append('C:/Python')` | `from db import db_connect, db_disconnect`

Answer (score -3):

A melhor abordagem será criar um pacote com a funcionalidade descrita e depois utilizar esse pacote nas aplicações que você precisar.
Assim futuras modificações no pacote refletem-se da mesma maneira nas aplicações que estão usando esse pacote.
Para mais detalhes veja a documentação oficial do Python, ou algum outro material de apoio na internet.

https://packaging.python.org/pt_BR/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/